# Glide хранение кеша

Tags: java, android, кэширование, glide

В приложения для загрузки изображений используются Glide. Как известно Glide кеширует изображения. При повторной попытке загрузить изображения он  выводит изображения из кеша. Так получилось что я поменял изображения на сервере но из-за кеширование в приложении изменение не видно.

Сколько времени нужно Glide чтобы кеш устарел и он загрузил новое изображения?

Comment: Кеш в Glide работает немного не так, старые записи удаляются по переполнению кеша.

Comment: @Valeriy тоесть он не удалиться через какое то время?

Comment: Нет, вот схожий вопрос на GitHub-e: https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/3242#issuecomment-412253016

Comment: Может стоит удалить кеш приложения обычными методами пользовательского андроида? (Настройки-приложения-ваше приложение)

Comment: @Yellastro этим я удалю кеш на своем телефоне. А этим приложением пользуются около 7тыс человек

Comment: @Valeriy Это что получается если глайд загружает два маленьких изображения то кеш не переполниться и не обновиться?

Comment: Получается что так. Думаю стоит начать изучать вопрос отсюда: https://bumptech.github.io/glide/javadocs/420/com/bumptech/glide/load/engine/cache/DiskCache.html или на странице разработчиков: https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues

Comment: P.S. Вы бы удалили эту тему, раз она не выгорила: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/899439/glide-%D1%81%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B0?rq=1

Comment: @Valeriy Удалил. Спасибо за помощь

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я думаю вам придется обновить свое приложение (клиентскую часть). Причем обновить способ генерации хэша по которому кэшируются картинки - прочтите [Custom Cache Invalidation](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/wiki/Caching-and-Cache-Invalidation#custom-cache-invalidation)

```
Glide.with(yourFragment)
    .load(yourFileDataModel)
    .signature(new StringSignature(yourVersionMetadata))
    .into(yourImageView);
```

Где `StringSignature` вычисляет хэш не по имени файла/Uri, а по его времени модификации и имени. Так что в следующий раз, когда вы поменяете свои файлы на сервере, то кэш автоматически обновится (поскольку время модификации поменяется).

Грубо говоря, Glide работает так:

1. Встречает файл/Uri
2. Вычисляет от него хэш
3. По этому хэшу ищет у себя в кэше файл и подгружает его

по умолчанию Glide вычисляет хэш по имени файла/Uri, а вам нужно чтобы он еще учитывал время его модификации.

Comment: Да я так и собираюсь и сделать. Просто не хочется лишний раз обновления выпускать.